# Firebase authState on protected routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm trying to redirect on the signin page if the user is not logged on firebase. I've done a PrivateRoute who check the user's state, if it isn't logged it will be redirect.
The problem:
When I put the login info it won't do nothing. if I put again, then I will redirect to the protected homepage. It seems that the state won't refresh after the first login, but on the second it is.

Signin Components:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Wrapper from '../../../utils/Wrapper';
import * as authFunctions from '../../../Functions/Auth';
import * as constants from "../../../utils/Constants";
import * as errorsFirebase from "../../../utils/FirebaseErrors";
import globalCss from "../../Style/Global.css";
import css from "../Signin/Signin.css";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import {  Row, Col } from 'react-flexbox-grid';
import * as localization from '../../../Localization';
import Input from '../../Input/Input';
import LoginContainer from '../LoginContainer'

class Signin extends Component{
    constructor(args){
        super(args);
        this.state = {
            user:null,
            auth: {}
        }
    }

    loginSuccess = (user)=>{
        //redirect to home:
        this.props.history.push(constants.HOME);
    }

    loginError = (error) =>{
        const tempState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state));
        switch(error.code){
            case errorsFirebase.LOGIN_BAD_FORMAT_EMAIL:
                tempState.auth.error = localization.stringsSignin.ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL;
                tempState.auth.errorEmail = true;
                break;
            case errorsFirebase.LOGIN_INVALID_PASSWORD:
                tempState.auth.error = localization.stringsSignin.ERROR_INVALID_PASSWORD;
                tempState.auth.errorPassword = true;
                break;
            case errorsFirebase.LOGIN_USER_NOT_FOUND:
                tempState.auth.error = localization.stringsSignin.ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND;
                tempState.auth.errorLogin = true;
                break;
            default:
                tempState.auth.error = localization.stringsSignin.ERROR_INVALID_PASSWORD;
                break;
        }
        this.setState(tempState);
    }

    loginHandler = (email,psw) =>{
        authFunctions.login(email,psw,this.loginSuccess, this.loginError);
    };

    onInputChange = (e) =>{
        const tempState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state));
        if(e.target.id === "email")
            tempState.auth.email = e.target.value;
        if(e.target.id === "psw")
            tempState.auth.psw = e.target.value;

        tempState.auth.error = null;
        tempState.auth.errorLogin = false;
        tempState.auth.errorPassword = false;
        tempState.auth.errorEmail = false;
        this.setState(tempState);
    }

    render() {
        const hasErrorEmail = this.state.auth.errorEmail?this.state.auth.errorEmail:false;
        const hasErrorPassword = this.state.auth.errorPassword?this.state.auth.errorPassword:false;
        const hasErrorLogin = this.state.auth.errorLogin?this.state.auth.errorLogin:false;
        const error = this.state.auth.error ? this.state.auth.error:"";
        return (
            <Wrapper>
                <LoginContainer>
                    <Row className="margin-top-30">
                        <Col xs={10}>
                            <p className="Right-title"> {localization.stringsSignin.RIGHT_TITLE} </p>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                        <Col xs={10} className="White-Base">
                            <Input xs={12}
                                   label={localization.stringsSignin.LABEL_USERNAME}
                                   inputId="email"
                                   inputType="email"
                                   hasError={hasErrorEmail || hasErrorLogin}
                                   change={this.onInputChange.bind(this)}/>
                            <Input xs={12}
                                   label={localization.stringsSignin.LABEL_PASSWORD}
                                   inputId="psw"
                                   inputType="password"
                                   hasError={hasErrorPassword || hasErrorLogin}
                                   change={this.onInputChange.bind(this)}/>
                            <Col xs={12}>&nbsp;</Col>
                            <Col xs={12}>
                                <p className="error">{error}</p>
                            </Col>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                        <Col xs={12} className="button-container">
                            <button className="btn-dark btn-sign" onClick={this.loginHandler.bind(this,this.state.auth.email,this.state.auth.psw)}>Sign In</button>
                            <Link className="forgot-Password" to={constants.FORGOT}>Forgot Password?</Link>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </LoginContainer>
            </Wrapper>
        )
    }
}

export default Signin;;
```

The app.js for the routing:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Wrapper from '../src/utils/Wrapper';
import Signin from '../src/components/Login/Signin/Signin';
import Signout from '../src/components/Login/Signout/Signout';
import Forgot from '../src/components/Login/Forgot/Forgot';
import ChangePassword from '../src/components/Login/ChangePassword/ChangePassword';
import UserActivity from '../src/components/Home/UserActivity/UserActivity'
import ManageQuizzes from '../src/components/Home/ManageQuizzes/ManageQuizzes'
import ManageProducts from '../src/components/Home/ManageProducts/ManageProducts'
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import firebase from 'firebase'
import * as constants from "./utils/Constants";
import PrivateRoute from './components/Route/PrivateRoute/PrivateRoute';
import PageNotFound from './components/PageNotFound/PageNotFound';
import {FirebaseAuth} from "./utils/Firebase";

class App extends Component {
    constructor(args){
        super(args);
        this.state = {
            authUser:null,
            isLoading:true
        }
    }

    authUser = () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
                this.setState({isLoading:false});
                if (user) {
                    resolve(user);
                } else {
                    reject("not logged")
                }
            });
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.authUser().then((user) => {
            this.setState({ authUser: user });
        }, ((e)=>{
            this.setState({ authUser: null });
        }));
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.isLoading) return null;
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Wrapper>
                    <Switch>
                        <PrivateRoute path={constants.HOME}  exact component={UserActivity} authUser={this.state.authUser}/>
                        <PrivateRoute path={constants.MANAGE_QUIZZES}  exact component={ManageQuizzes}/>}/>
                        <PrivateRoute path={constants.MANAGE_PRODUCTS} exact component={ManageProducts}/>}/>

                        <Route path={constants.SIGNIN} exact component={Signin}/>
                        <Route path={constants.FORGOT} exact component={Forgot}/>
                        <Route path={constants.CHANGE_PASSWORD} exact component={ChangePassword}/>
                        <Route path={constants.SIGNOUT} exact component={Signout}/>}/>

                        /*Last component MUST the 404*/
                        <Route component={PageNotFound}/>
                    </Switch>
                </Wrapper>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

The PrivateRoute:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import * as constants from '../../../utils/Constants'
import firebase from 'firebase';

const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, authUser, ...rest}) => {
    console.log("PrivateRoute", authUser);

    return (
        <Route
                {...rest}
                render={(props) => authUser!=null
        ? <Component {...props} />
        : <Redirect to={{pathname: constants.SIGNIN, state: {from: props.location}}} />}
            />

    )
}

export default PrivateRoute
```

I prefere to don't use redux.

Thanks

Comment: So... The redirect when the user is not logged in works, but what doesn't work is when you successfully log in and want to be redirected to the Home page, am I right?

Comment: yes.. here the scenario:
user login in signin page. firebase say "ok you are logged in" but the router doesn't know yet. infact the protected routing have logged = false and it will redirect back to the signin page again. If the user will insert again the credential, the redirect to the home will work. I think I'm missing something in the flow.. i'm a newbie.
The signin.js is a component with a state. The app.js have the routing system, but have an old state with the user is not logged in. I think I must tell something to the app.js, like in the succesful login in the signin.js.

Comment: Could you show your `authFunctions.login` method?

Comment: export function login (email, pw, successCallback, errorCallback) {
    if(!pw) {
        //Firebase it seems break if you don't put a psw (at least at the first time)
        const fakeObjError = [];
        fakeObjError.code = errorsFirebase.LOGIN_INVALID_PASSWORD;
        errorCallback(fakeObjError);
        return;
    }
    return FirebaseAuth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pw).then(function(user){
        successCallback(user)
    }).catch(function(error) {
        errorCallback(error)
    });
}
and the success callback is just this.props.history.push(constants.HOME);

Answer (score 0):

I finnaly found a solution. For what i've understood the problem was in the routing process and for resolve it i've added a redux-store for save login infos. So:

in the signin component, when I call firebase for login it will set a record on a store on a succesful login:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Wrapper from '../../../utils/Wrapper';
import * as authFunctions from '../../../Functions/Auth';
import * as constants from "../../../utils/Constants";
import * as errorsFirebase from "../../../utils/FirebaseErrors";
import globalCss from "../../Style/Global.css";
import css from "../Signin/Signin.css";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import {  Row, Col } from 'react-flexbox-grid';
import * as localization from '../../../Localization';
import Input from '../../Input/Input';
import LoginContainer from '../LoginContainer'
import AdminUser from '../../../hoc/AdminUser/AdminUser';
import {connect} from 'react-redux'

class Signin extends Component{
    constructor(args){
        super(args);
        this.state = {
            errorLogin:null,
            auth: {}
        }
    }

    loginSuccess = (user)=>{
        const adminUser =  AdminUser.getInstance(user);
        this.props.onAdminLoggedIn(adminUser);
        this.props.history.push(constants.HOME);
    }

    loginError = (error) =>{
        const tempState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state));
        switch(error.code){
            case errorsFirebase.LOGIN_BAD_FORMAT_EMAIL:
                tempState.auth.error = localization.stringsSignin.ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL;
                tempState.auth.errorEmail = true;
                break;
            case errorsFirebase.LOGIN_INVALID_PASSWORD:
                tempState.auth.error = localization.stringsSignin.ERROR_INVALID_PASSWORD;
                tempState.auth.errorPassword = true;
                break;
            case errorsFirebase.LOGIN_USER_NOT_FOUND:
                tempState.auth.error = localization.stringsSignin.ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND;
                tempState.auth.errorLogin = true;
                break;
            default:
                tempState.auth.error = localization.stringsSignin.ERROR_INVALID_PASSWORD;
                break;
        }
        this.setState(tempState);
    }

    loginHandler = (email,psw) =>{
        if(this.state.errorLogin === null)  authFunctions.login(email,psw,this.loginSuccess, this.loginError);
    };

    onInputChange = (e) =>{
        const tempState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state));
        if(e.target.id === "email")
            tempState.auth.email = e.target.value;
        if(e.target.id === "psw")
            tempState.auth.psw = e.target.value;

        tempState.auth.error = null;
        tempState.auth.errorLogin = false;
        tempState.auth.errorPassword = false;
        tempState.auth.errorEmail = false;
        this.setState(tempState);
    }

    render() {
        const hasErrorEmail = this.state.auth.errorEmail?this.state.auth.errorEmail:false;
        const hasErrorPassword = this.state.auth.errorPassword?this.state.auth.errorPassword:false;
        const hasErrorLogin = this.state.auth.errorLogin?this.state.auth.errorLogin:false;
        const error = this.state.auth.error ? this.state.auth.error:"";
        return (
            <Wrapper>
                <LoginContainer>
                    <Row className="margin-top-30">
                        <Col xs={10}>
                            <p className="Right-title"> {localization.stringsSignin.RIGHT_TITLE} </p>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                        <Col xs={10} className="White-Base">
                            <Input xs={12}
                                   label={localization.stringsSignin.LABEL_USERNAME}
                                   inputId="email"
                                   inputType="email"
                                   hasError={hasErrorEmail || hasErrorLogin}
                                   change={this.onInputChange.bind(this)}/>
                            <Input xs={12}
                                   label={localization.stringsSignin.LABEL_PASSWORD}
                                   inputId="psw"
                                   inputType="password"
                                   hasError={hasErrorPassword || hasErrorLogin}
                                   change={this.onInputChange.bind(this)}/>
                            <Col xs={12}>&nbsp;</Col>
                            <Col xs={12}>
                                <p className="error">{error}</p>
                            </Col>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                        <Col xs={12} className="button-container">
                            <button className="btn-dark btn-sign" onClick={this.loginHandler.bind(this,this.state.auth.email,this.state.auth.psw)}>Sign In</button>
                            <Link className="forgot-Password" to={constants.FORGOT}>Forgot Password?</Link>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </LoginContainer>
            </Wrapper>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state =>{
    return {
        ctr: state
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>{
    return {
        onAdminLoggedIn : (user) =>{
            dispatch({type: constants.REDUX_PUT_USER_STATE,payload:user})
        },
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Signin);
```

the browser router will pass the info of the stored user to the protected router:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Wrapper from '../src/utils/Wrapper';
import Signin from '../src/components/Login/Signin/Signin';
import Signup from '../src/components/Login/Signup/Signup';
import Signout from '../src/components/Login/Signout/Signout';
import Forgot from '../src/components/Login/Forgot/Forgot';
import ChangePassword from '../src/components/Login/ChangePassword/ChangePassword';
import UserActivity from '../src/components/Home/UserActivity/UserActivity'
import ManageQuizzes from '../src/components/Home/ManageQuizzes/ManageQuizzes'
import ManageProducts from '../src/components/Home/ManageProducts/ManageProducts'
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import firebase from 'firebase'
import * as constants from "./utils/Constants";
import PrivateRoute from './components/Route/PrivateRoute/PrivateRoute';
import PageNotFound from './components/PageNotFound/PageNotFound';
import {FirebaseAuth} from "./utils/Firebase";
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import AdminUser from './hoc/AdminUser/AdminUser';


class App extends Component {
    constructor(args){
        super(args);
        this.state = {
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
            const adminUser =  AdminUser.getInstance(user);
            this.props.onAdminLoggedIn(adminUser);
        })
    }

    render() {
        if(this.props.ctr.user === null) return null;
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Wrapper>
                    <Switch>
                        <PrivateRoute path={constants.HOME}  exact component={UserActivity} authUser={this.props.ctr.user} />
                        <PrivateRoute path={constants.MANAGE_QUIZZES}  exact component={ManageQuizzes} authUser={this.props.ctr.user}/>
                        <PrivateRoute path={constants.MANAGE_PRODUCTS} exact component={ManageProducts} authUser={this.props.ctr.user}/>}/>
                        /*Admin users can only sign up for testing*/
                        <PrivateRoute path={constants.SIGNUP}  exact component={Signup} authUser/>
                        /*-----*/
                        <Route path={constants.SIGNIN} exact component={Signin}/>
                        <Route path={constants.FORGOT} exact component={Forgot}/>
                        <Route path={constants.CHANGE_PASSWORD} exact component={ChangePassword}/>
                        <Route path={constants.SIGNOUT} exact component={Signout}/>}/>



                        /*Last component MUST the 404*/
                        <Route component={PageNotFound}/>
                    </Switch>
                </Wrapper>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state =>{
    return {
        ctr: state
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>{
    return {
        onAdminLoggedIn : (user) =>{
            dispatch({type: constants.REDUX_PUT_USER_STATE,payload:user})
        },
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

finally the private router who manage the redirect:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import * as constants from '../../../utils/Constants'
import firebase from 'firebase';

const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, authUser, ...rest}) => {
    return (
        <Route
                {...rest}
                render={(props) => (authUser?true:false)
        ? <Component {...props} />
        : <Redirect to={{pathname: constants.SIGNIN, state: {from: props.location}}} />}
            />

    )
}

export default PrivateRoute
```

In conclusion, without use a redux store I couldn't find a solution. This is because (imo) there are too many variables in the scenario:

- the firebase asyncing,
- the change page from the signin
- the change page from the PrivetRoute
- the routing